# Ruby how can I save an instance of a class with JSON?

Tags: ruby, json

I have this code:

```
require 'json'

class A
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c
  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @a = a, @b = b, @c = c
  end
end

a = A.new(1, "a", [1, 2, 3])
p a

puts "\n\nJSON: "
puts a.to_json


puts "\n\nJSON.pretty_generate: "
puts JSON.pretty_generate(a)
```

Output is really dissapointing:

```
#<A:0x000000019f4678 @b="a", @c=[1, 2, 3], @a=[1, "a", [1, 2, 3]]>


JSON: 
"#<A:0x000000019f4678>"


JSON pretty generate: 
blahblah.rb:285:in `generate': only generation of JSON objects
or arrays allowed (JSON::GeneratorError)
```

What's the difference between instance of class and JSON object?
How to convert instance of class to JSON object?

Comment: There's *data* and there is *code*. JSON is a format to interchange data, whereas a class is code.

Comment: When you say "class" do you mean "instance of a class"?

Comment: Yes I mean instance of class.

Comment: `@a = a, @b = b, @c = c` almost certainly does not what you expect.

Answer (score 7):

> How to convert instance of class to JSON object?

Ruby's JSON implementation can serialize/deserialize custom objects, but you have to provide the details, i.e.

1. a `to_json` instance method that returns a JSON representation from your object and
2. a `json_create` class method that creates an object from its JSON representation

Here's an example using your class:

```
require 'json'

class A
  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c

  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @a, @b, @c = a, b, c
  end

  def to_json(*args)
    {
      JSON.create_id => self.class.name,
      'a' => a,
      'b' => b,
      'c' => c
    }.to_json(*args)
  end

  def self.json_create(h)
    new(h['a'], h['b'], h['c'])
  end
end

a = A.new(1, 'a', [1, 2, 3])
#=> #<A:0x007f92cc8f37f0 @a=1, @b="a", @c=[1, 2, 3]>

a.to_json
#=> "{\"json_class\":\"A\",\"a\":1,\"b\":\"a\",\"c\":[1,2,3]}"
```

`JSON.create_id` defaults to the string `"json_class"`. It's a special identifier that is recognizes by [`parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-i-parse) if you pass `create_additions: true`:

```
JSON.parse(a.to_json, create_additions: true)
#<A:0x007ff59c0f2578 @a=1, @b="a", @c=[1, 2, 3]>
```

Without this option, the parser doesn't invoke `A.json_create` and returns a plain hash instead:

```
JSON.parse(a.to_json)
#=> {"json_class"=>"A", "a"=>1, "b"=>"a", "c"=>[1, 2, 3]}
```

Calling `JSON.pretty_generate(a)` generates the following output:

```
{
  "json_class": "A",
  "a": 1,
  "b": "a",
  "c": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Stefan this was helpful. I'm curious however will this work if you START with pure json rather than using the objects to_json method first? JSON.parse has an object_class option which I would assume sets the "json_class" property, but I can't get this to work. I get 'wrong number of arguments' error from initialize. If I do exactly what you have done it does work, but if I start with a json object without the 'json_class' property I can't get it to work. The 'object_class' option is very poorly documented so maybe it doesn't do what I am expecting?

Comment: @RobCarpenter I don't want to start a comment thread on a 3 year old answer. You might want to post a new question instead.

Answer (score 4):

One thing is a Ruby [class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Class.html):

From Wikipedia:

> In object-oriented programming, a class is an extensible
>   program-code-template for creating objects, providing initial values
>   for state (member variables) and implementations of behavior (member
>   functions or methods).

and the other is a [JSON object](http://www.w3schools.com/json/):

> JSON: JavaScript Object Notation.
>
> JSON is a syntax for storing and exchanging data.
>
> JSON is an easier-to-use alternative to XML.

This is a well-known problem when serving data from the server to a web browser. You send a JSON representation of the data, normally for working in the server you parse this data to a Ruby object.

The error:

http://apidock.com/ruby/JSON/pretty_generate

You can only parse simple objects to JSON, you cannot parse a String. In order to this you can add the `to_json` method inside class `A`:

```
irb(main):046:0> JSON.pretty_generate("calimero")
JSON::GeneratorError: only generation of JSON objects or arrays allowed
    from /Users/toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@stackoverflow/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:285:in `generate'
    from /Users/toni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3@stackoverflow/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:285:in `pretty_generate'
    from (irb):59
    from /Users/toni/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
irb(main):060:0> JSON.pretty_generate([1,2,3])
=> "[\n  1,\n  2,\n  3\n]"
```

I recommend using the [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) gem. It clarifies  the type of the object are you going to parse to JSON, which for me is a good practice  knowing what are you converting to JSON and what data are you expecting:

```
require 'virtus'
require 'json'

class A
  include Virtus.model

  attr_accessor :a, :b, :c

  attribute :a, Integer
  attribute :b, String
  attribute :c, Array[Integer]

  def initialize(a, b, c)
    @a = a, @b = b, @c = c
  end                    

end



irb(main):039:0> a = A.new(1, "a", [1, 2, 3])
=> #<A:0x007fc391882ac8 @b="a", @c=[1, 2, 3], @a=[1, "a", [1, 2, 3]]>
irb(main):040:0> a.attributes
=> {:a=>[1, "a", [1, 2, 3]], :b=>"a", :c=>[1, 2, 3]}
irb(main):053:0> require 'json'
=> true
irb(main):085:0> a.attributes.to_json
=> "{\"a\":[1,\"a\",[1,2,3]],\"b\":\"a\",\"c\":[1,2,3]}"
irb(main):096:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would look at serializing the data instead, and make your class works so it can respond with the attributes rather easily.

```
require 'json'

class A
  ATTRS = [:a, :b, :c]
  attr_accessor *ATTRS
  def initialize(params)
    params.each do |k, v|
      self.send("#{k}=".to_sym, v)
    end
  end

  def attributes
    values = {}
    ATTRS.each do |key|
      values[key] = self.send(key)
    end
    values
  end
end

a = A.new(a: 1, b: "a", c: [1, 2, 3])
p a

data = a.attributes.to_json
puts data
b = A.new(JSON.parse(data))

p b
```

To explain this a bit, I'm using send to call the writable method for each attribute in the constructor, this goes through the params and sets the instance variable values.

The attributes method then uses the ATTRS constant array to build out an object map of just the properties of this instance. So we serialize that, and de-serialize to make a new instance.

This is pretty much how rails does it, though ActiveRecord uses an attributes hash for storing the properties over traditional accessors.

Comment: I don't see how this would work when class A also contains array of class B, which contain further classes. ECMASCRIPT 6 supports classes, but JSON still does not? That is really confusing me.

Comment: JSON is a data format, not code serialization. JSON cannot serialize functions. Ideally you shouldn't serialize or store methods/functions, as that would be caching the behaviour. What if you did have that data on a client somewhere, but your backend was updated. The stored object would no longer work the way it's expected to.