# Deserializing JSON to a custom object NOT USING OpenStruct in Ruby

Tags: json, ruby

How can I deserialize an JSON object that looks like this (test data from a real Wells Fargo API response):

```
data = {
  "accounts": [
    {
      "bank_id": "091000019",
      "account_number": "23784275367",
      "account_type": "DEMAND_DEPOSIT",
      "account_name": "QUALITY LIFE MUSSMAN CO",
      "currency_code": "USD",
      "transaction_count": 5,
      "transactions": [
        {
          "posting_date": "2019-06-04",
          "value_date": "2019-06-04",
          "transaction_datetime": "2019-06-04 03:12:00Z",
          "debit_credit_indicator": "DEBIT",
          "transaction_type": "CHECK",
          "bai_type_code": "045",
          "transaction_description": "BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950",
          "transaction_amount": 224.43,
          "zero_day_float": 0,
          "one_day_float": 0,
          "two_date_float": 0,
          "check_number": "0000",
          "bank_reference": "082300000022",
          "transaction_status": "POSTED"
        },
        {
          "posting_date": "2019-06-04",
          "value_date": "2019-06-04",
          "transaction_datetime": "2019-06-04 02:12:00Z",
          "debit_credit_indicator": "DEBIT",
          "transaction_type": "CHECK",
          "bai_type_code": "045",
          "transaction_description": "BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950",
          "transaction_amount": 224.43,
          "zero_day_float": 0,
          "one_day_float": 0,
          "two_date_float": 0,
          "check_number": "0000",
          "bank_reference": "082300000022",
          "transaction_status": "POSTED"
        },
        {
          "posting_date": "2019-06-04",
          "value_date": "2019-06-04",
          "transaction_datetime": "2019-06-04 01:12:00Z",
          "debit_credit_indicator": "DEBIT",
          "transaction_type": "CHECK",
          "bai_type_code": "045",
          "transaction_description": "BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950",
          "transaction_amount": 224.43,
          "zero_day_float": 0,
          "one_day_float": 0,
          "two_date_float": 0,
          "check_number": "0000",
          "bank_reference": "082300000022",
          "transaction_status": "POSTED"
        },
        {
          "posting_date": "2019-06-03",
          "value_date": "2019-06-03",
          "transaction_datetime": "2019-06-03 16:18:20Z",
          "debit_credit_indicator": "DEBIT",
          "transaction_type": "CHECK",
          "bai_type_code": "045",
          "transaction_description": "BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950",
          "transaction_amount": 224.43,
          "zero_day_float": 0,
          "one_day_float": 0,
          "two_date_float": 0,
          "check_number": "0000",
          "bank_reference": "082300000022",
          "transaction_status": "POSTED"
        },
        {
          "posting_date": "2019-06-02",
          "value_date": "2019-06-02",
          "transaction_datetime": "2019-06-02 16:18:20Z",
          "debit_credit_indicator": "DEBIT",
          "transaction_type": "CHECK",
          "bai_type_code": "045",
          "transaction_description": "BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950",
          "transaction_amount": 244.55,
          "zero_day_float": 0,
          "one_day_float": 0,
          "two_date_float": 0,
          "check_number": "0000",
          "bank_reference": "082300000022",
          "transaction_status": "POSTED"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

into a CUSTOM ruby object with other custom nested objects (Accounts, and Transactions)? I've seen a lot of people using OpenStruct but I don't want to use OpenStruct. I want to build the object myself and pass it using `object_class` to the JSON parser.

This SO post started me down a path:

[Ruby how can I save an instance of a class with JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36983364/ruby-how-can-i-save-an-instance-of-a-class-with-json)

But I don't want to have to create the object first then convert it to JSON just to parse it. I want to go from JSON straight to custom object. Has anyone figured out how to do this without using OpenStruct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I scoured SO looking for an answer and everyone used OpenStruct if anything to achieve deserialization into an object. However the JSON.parse function has an `object_class` property that I was determined could do what I wanted, and in the end... I was right. Using this syntax:

```rb
tc = JSON.parse(data.to_json, object_class: TransactionDetail::Collection, create_additions: true)
```

you can turn a data object (test data from an actual Wells Fargo API response):

```
data = {
  "accounts": [
    {
      "bank_id": "091000019",
      "account_number": "23784275367",
      "account_type": "DEMAND_DEPOSIT",
      "account_name": "QUALITY LIFE MUSSMAN CO",
      "currency_code": "USD",
      "transaction_count": 5,
      "transactions": [
        {
          "posting_date": "2019-06-04",
          "value_date": "2019-06-04",
          "transaction_datetime": "2019-06-04 03:12:00Z",
          "debit_credit_indicator": "DEBIT",
          "transaction_type": "CHECK",
          "bai_type_code": "045",
          "transaction_description": "BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950",
          "transaction_amount": 224.43,
          "zero_day_float": 0,
          "one_day_float": 0,
          "two_date_float": 0,
          "check_number": "0000",
          "bank_reference": "082300000022",
          "transaction_status": "POSTED"
        },
        {
          "posting_date": "2019-06-04",
          "value_date": "2019-06-04",
          "transaction_datetime": "2019-06-04 02:12:00Z",
          "debit_credit_indicator": "DEBIT",
          "transaction_type": "CHECK",
          "bai_type_code": "045",
          "transaction_description": "BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950",
          "transaction_amount": 224.43,
          "zero_day_float": 0,
          "one_day_float": 0,
          "two_date_float": 0,
          "check_number": "0000",
          "bank_reference": "082300000022",
          "transaction_status": "POSTED"
        },
        {
          "posting_date": "2019-06-04",
          "value_date": "2019-06-04",
          "transaction_datetime": "2019-06-04 01:12:00Z",
          "debit_credit_indicator": "DEBIT",
          "transaction_type": "CHECK",
          "bai_type_code": "045",
          "transaction_description": "BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950",
          "transaction_amount": 224.43,
          "zero_day_float": 0,
          "one_day_float": 0,
          "two_date_float": 0,
          "check_number": "0000",
          "bank_reference": "082300000022",
          "transaction_status": "POSTED"
        },
        {
          "posting_date": "2019-06-03",
          "value_date": "2019-06-03",
          "transaction_datetime": "2019-06-03 16:18:20Z",
          "debit_credit_indicator": "DEBIT",
          "transaction_type": "CHECK",
          "bai_type_code": "045",
          "transaction_description": "BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950",
          "transaction_amount": 224.43,
          "zero_day_float": 0,
          "one_day_float": 0,
          "two_date_float": 0,
          "check_number": "0000",
          "bank_reference": "082300000022",
          "transaction_status": "POSTED"
        },
        {
          "posting_date": "2019-06-02",
          "value_date": "2019-06-02",
          "transaction_datetime": "2019-06-02 16:18:20Z",
          "debit_credit_indicator": "DEBIT",
          "transaction_type": "CHECK",
          "bai_type_code": "045",
          "transaction_description": "BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950",
          "transaction_amount": 244.55,
          "zero_day_float": 0,
          "one_day_float": 0,
          "two_date_float": 0,
          "check_number": "0000",
          "bank_reference": "082300000022",
          "transaction_status": "POSTED"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

into the following custom object, with nested custom objects.

```
> tc
#<TransactionDetail::Collection:0x00007fa690053708 @data={
"json_class"=>"TransactionDetail::Collection", 
:accounts=>{23784275367=>
#<TransactionDetail::Account:0x00007fa690053f50 
@json_class="TransactionDetail::Collection", 
@bank_id="091000019", @account_number="23784275367", 
@account_type="DEMAND_DEPOSIT", @account_name="QUALITY LIFE MUSSMAN CO", 
@currency_code="USD", @transaction_count=10, @transactions=[
#<TransactionDetail::Transaction:0x00007fa69004b918 
@json_class="TransactionDetail::Collection", @posting_date="2019-06-04", 
@value_date="2019-06-04", @transaction_datetime="2019-06-04 03:12:00Z", 
@debit_credit_indicator="DEBIT", @transaction_type="CHECK", 
@bai_type_code="045", @transaction_description="BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950", 
@transaction_amount=224.43, @zero_day_float=0, @one_day_float=0, 
@two_date_float=0, @check_number="0000", 
@bank_reference="082300000022", @transaction_status="POSTED">, 
#<TransactionDetail::Transaction:0x00007fa690049ca8 
@json_class="TransactionDetail::Collection", @posting_date="2019-06-04", 
@value_date="2019-06-04", @transaction_datetime="2019-06-04 02:12:00Z", 
@debit_credit_indicator="DEBIT", @transaction_type="CHECK", 
@bai_type_code="045", @transaction_description="BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950", 
@transaction_amount=224.43, @zero_day_float=0, @one_day_float=0, 
@two_date_float=0, @check_number="0000", 
@bank_reference="082300000022", @transaction_status="POSTED">, 
#<TransactionDetail::Transaction:0x00007fa69004f298 
@json_class="TransactionDetail::Collection", @posting_date="2019-06-04", 
@value_date="2019-06-04", @transaction_datetime="2019-06-04 01:12:00Z", 
@debit_credit_indicator="DEBIT", @transaction_type="CHECK", 
@bai_type_code="045", @transaction_description="BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950", 
@transaction_amount=224.43, @zero_day_float=0, @one_day_float=0, 
@two_date_float=0, @check_number="0000", 
@bank_reference="082300000022", @transaction_status="POSTED">, 
#<TransactionDetail::Transaction:0x00007fa69004e028 
@json_class="TransactionDetail::Collection", @posting_date="2019-06-03", 
@value_date="2019-06-03", @transaction_datetime="2019-06-03 16:18:20Z", 
@debit_credit_indicator="DEBIT", @transaction_type="CHECK", 
@bai_type_code="045", @transaction_description="BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950", @transaction_amount=224.43, 
@zero_day_float=0, @one_day_float=0, @two_date_float=0, 
@check_number="0000", @bank_reference="082300000022", 
@transaction_status="POSTED">, 
#<TransactionDetail::Transaction:0x00007fa69004cde0 
@json_class="TransactionDetail::Collection", @posting_date="2019-06-02", 
@value_date="2019-06-02", @transaction_datetime="2019-06-02 16:18:20Z", 
@debit_credit_indicator="DEBIT", @transaction_type="CHECK", 
@bai_type_code="045", @transaction_description="BANK ORIGINATED DEBIT FR 0000007186 THE SHERWIN-WILLIAMS COMPANY SUB ACCT 000004944938950", 
@transaction_amount=244.55, @zero_day_float=0, @one_day_float=0, 
@two_date_float=0, @check_number="0000", 
@bank_reference="082300000022", @transaction_status="POSTED">]>}, :account_array=>[23784275367]}>
```

Here is how I went about deserializing. Below is my `object_class` that I pass to the parser.

```rb
require 'json'
require 'active_support/core_ext/object/try'
require 'forwardable'

module TransactionDetail

  def initialize_instance_variables(o)
    o.data.each do |key, value|
      instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value)
      self.class.send(:attr_reader, key)
    end
  end

  class Collection
    extend Forwardable

    def_delegators :@data, :account, :list_accounts, :transactions
    attr_accessor :data

    def initialize(o = nil)
      @data = {
        JSON.create_id => self.class.name
      }
      if o != nil && o.kind_of?(TransactionDetail::Collection)
        @data[:accounts] = {}
        @data[:account_array] = []
        o.data['accounts'].each do |a|
          @data[:account_array] << a.account_number.to_i
          @data[:accounts][a.account_number.to_i] = a
        end
      end
    end

    def json_creatable?
      true
    end

    def [](index)
     @data[index]
    end

    def []=(index, new_value)
      @data[index] = new_value
    end

    def self.json_create(o)
      if o.data.key? 'bank_id'
        return TransactionDetail::Account.new(o)
      end
      if o.data.key? 'transaction_amount'
        return TransactionDetail::Transaction.new(o)
      end
      new(o)
    end

    def list_accounts
      @data[:account_array]
    end

    def account(account_number)
      @data[:accounts][account_number]
    end

    def transactions(account_number)
      @data[:accounts][account_number].transactions
    end
  end

  class Account
    include TransactionDetail
    def initialize(o)
      initialize_instance_variables(o)
    end
  end

  class Transaction
    include TransactionDetail
    def initialize(o)
      initialize_instance_variables(o)
    end
  end
end
```

The `object_class` property is pretty poorly documented, but works well. The source code for the pure ruby version of the JSON parser was what led to the breakthrough in how to use this property.

The trick is understanding that the `object_class` merely tells the parser what to do when it "runs into" an object while parsing your JSON structure. Otherwise it will happily parse strings and bools and types that it knows how to handle. If you have a specific object in mind that you want to return you have to tell the parser what to do in the `json_create` function. If you set all the required properties:

1) object_class must be initialized with a hash that holds `JSON.create_id => self.class.name` (its the first thing the parser looks for and then instantiates an empty instance of this class to begin building on) This is shown in my Collection class's initialize method.

2) Must pass both the `object_class` and `create_additions: true` the the `JSON.parse` method.

3) Not 100% sure on this one but I believe you need `json_creatable?` to return true in your `object_class`

With all this set when the parser sees an object in the JSON structure it hands off the parsing job to your `json_create` function and walks the nested structure.

In my `json_create` method I pick out certain keys that I know will be in the JSON response and if I detect those I build the appropriate object and return it to the parser. The parser know where that object is in the nested structure and neatly places it there. The final step is to return the `object_class` itself, accomplished by the `new(o)` line. You can do some final reorganizing in your `object_class` initialize method as I've done, for example I gave all the accounts a Hash lookup by account number and added an array that has only account numbers.

Comment: Check out Dry::Struct. I'm 90% sure sure you can achieve the same effect, but with code that is clean and doesn't contain unnecessary hardcoded details. The cost is it's another dependency.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what isn't 'clean' about the code? The hardcoded details are absolutely necessary, I'm dealing with text and trying to determine what type of object to create based on text. Known keys are the only thing to, well, key off of. I'll check out dry struct but the thought of adding another dependency makes me cringe.

Comment: "The hardcoded details are absolutely necessary" - no, they aren't, actually. Your collections are homogeneous. Accounts array contains only accounts. And an account has many transactions (again, without any accounts mixed in). If you _really want_ do use the same class to deserialize both types, then you'll have to do some kind of switching on properties, yes. But why not use separate classes?

Comment: Your data is not of completely arbitrary shape. You _know_ you have a top-level array `accounts`. Why not leverage the fact/knowledge?

Comment: Your suggestion doesn't account for the way the object_class property works. You can only pass it one class, not multiple.

Comment: There actually are separate classes being used here if you look more closely. The top level Collection class is responsible for creating instances of the Account and Transaction class.

Comment: My suggestion does not involve `object_class` at all.

Comment: "There actually are separate classes" - nominally there are, but they aren't doing anything for you. All of the logic is still contained within the Collection. It knows how to tell transaction and account apart, for example. And none of your classes give any info about what the _actual_ content of transaction/account could look like. So I'm not sure why you'd prefer this to OpenStruct. I see only drawbacks.

Comment: They are doing something for me, I didn't post the entire class written for production here, just a sample. The classes have helper functions that aren't shown here. They are demonstrated by the helper functions on the Collection so I didn't think it was necessary to post all the code. OpenStruct wouldn't give me that. I tried to determine if dry-struct would but their docs are not very friendly. I think you only see drawbacks because you're limiting your sight to my small example and don't see the full use case clearly.

Comment: I'm struggling with your suggestion because you're tossing out a poorly documented library and telling me you're only 90% sure it can do what I want. I'm less sure after reading their docs. I'm not above being proven wrong though, but write some code if you want me to take your suggestion seriously. As for now I'm 100% my solution works and I'm happy with it.

Comment: I agree, dry-rb docs have room for improvement. I'll try to throw something together later today, but no promises :)